# On Minecraft Bedrock Edition, how do you find Mooshrooms?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I've looked in most biomes, but can't find the red Mooshroom.  How do I find them?

Comment: -1, this is something you can google. This shows no research effort.

Comment: Didn't know we were bothering you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mooshrooms can spawn on a mycelium island in the ocean. Mycelium islands can be great because no mobs spawn there! Mycelium islands look like grass islands, but the grass is gray instead of green, there are mushroom trees and mushrooms everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

In Bedrock Edition, [Mooshrooms](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Mooshroom#Bedrock_Edition) only spawn at a light level of 7 or higher, and in the Mushroom Fields or Mushrooms Field Shore biomes:

> Mooshrooms spawn at light level 7 or above in Mushroom Fields and Mushroom Field Shore biomes. 5% of them spawn as babies.

What makes it hard to find them is that the particular [biome](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Mushroom_Fields) they spawn in is quite rare.  These biomes seem to generate most commonly as islands in the ocean, so perhaps start searching around any oceans.

> The mushroom biome usually generates as a single island surrounded by ocean, though it occasionally generates touching land on a side